# API to read raw NDepend Metrics and Code data in SonarQube

Tags: api, sonarqube, ndepend

I'm using the NDepend Plugin for SonarQube to load metrics into SonarQube. I would like to know how to do one of the following,

1. How to get raw data xml data from NDepend plugin?
2. How to get the NDepend [Code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics) for each method (not the processed rules after the code metrics have been processed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the NDepend metrics in Sonarqube is not possible yet. However it's planned to add this feature.

Comment: Can you give an estimate by when this will happen? In the next release or further down the line?

Comment: Not within the next months, at best in 2017 Q3 Q4 timeframe but this is not exactly defined yet.